# Calculate "matrix of cofactors" in R?

Tags: r, matrix

Is there any way to calculate the `matrix of cofactors` in R directly?
(Without multiplying it by determinant!)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Matrix_of_cofactors

Answer (score 3):

Build your own function:

```
library(functional)

M<-matrix(1:9,3,3)

getCofactor = function(M, i, j)
{
    stopifnot(length(unique(dim(M)))==1)
    stopifnot(all(c(i,j)<=dim(M)))

    det(M[-i,-j])*(-1)^(i+j)
}

grid = expand.grid(1:dim(M)[1], 1:dim(M)[2])
matrix(mapply(Curry(getCofactor, M=M), grid$Var1, grid$Var2), nrow=dim(M)[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function that gives you the whole matrix of cofactors with one click.

```
getCofactors <- function(M) {
  stopifnot(length(unique(dim(M)))==1) # Check if Matrix = Square
  cf <- M # creating a Matrix that has the same Dimensions as M 
  for(i in 1:dim(M)[1]){
    for(j in 1:dim(M)[2]){
      cf[i,j] <- (det(M[-i,-j])*(-1)^(i+j)) # overwriting the Values of cf Matrix with cofactors
    }
  }
  return(cf) # output of cofactors matrix
}
```

If you Want you can save your function and load it on demand:

```
dump("getCofactors", file="getCofactors.R")
source("getCofactors.R")
```